# Matching Rules w/ Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to compare objects to a collection of rules stored in Mongo. Here is an example of an object and two rules:

Object:
{
     "color": "red"
    ,"make": "ford"
    ,"type": "sedan"
}

Rules:
[0]{
     "color": "red"
    ,"type": "suv"
}
[1]{
     "make": "ford"
}

In this example, only rule 1 should match. I have played around with different operators ($exists, $or, $and) but have had no luck making the results match the solution I am working on. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean at least one rule or EXACTLY one rule?  i.e. should red ford suv match here or not?

Comment: I want to be able to format object into a query and match on rules that apply.

i.e. 
> db.coll.find(<object formatted>)
> <rule 1>

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have trouble matching one of the rules using $or operator:

```
> db.obj.insert({ "color": "red" ,"make": "ford" ,"type": "sedan" })
Inserted 1 record(s) in 17ms
> db.obj.find({$or:[{color:"red", "type":"suv"}, {make:"ford"}]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518ac9be6c49c38046ac4b19"), "color" : "red", "make" : "ford", "type" : "sedan" }
>
```